# formbuilder inside a tabs component not working in angular 6

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular2-formbuilder

i am trying to build a form which is divided across mutiple tabs in a single component.
but formbuilder is throwing error saying that its not able to find the formControlName.

this is the stackblitz link[formBuilderInsideTabs](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nprf6q) and the error screenshot of the same.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMCAg.png)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
<my-tabs>
  <my-tab [tabTitle]="'Tab 1'">
    <form [formGroup]="MyGroup">
      <div formGroupName="averageMos">
        <input type="text" formControlName="critical">
      </div>
    </form>
  </my-tab>
  <my-tab tabTitle="Tab 2">
    Tab 2 content
  </my-tab>

</my-tabs>
```

Please note that I have used `formGroupName` and not `FormGroupName` in html.

[Here is the working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rakrvf?file=src/app/app.component.html)